# Determining number size in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, integer, hex, size

I am given the *hex number 0x04030201*, stored in the middle of an array filled with zeroes. My code has to determine the size of this number in **bits**.

I am required to implement this in 2 different ways. My first way was to use the `sizeof()` function like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num[] = {0,0,0x04030201,0,0};

    cout<<"The size of the integer is "<<sizeof(num[2])*4<<" bits."<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My expected output is 28 bits(4 bits times the 7 significant characters). But my output gives:

```
The size of the integer is 16 bits.
```

What's my mistake?

Comment: On your current platform 1 byte = 8 bits maybe? Expected output of 28 bits seems very unlikely...

Comment: sizeof is just returning the number of bytes of an integer since that is the type of num[2].  This is true regardless of the content of num[2].

Comment: A number is a number. There is no such thing as "a hex number".

Comment: Your solution doesn't obtain any characteristic of the value, only of the integer type that holds it.

Comment: There is a "smallest number of bits necessary to hold the value `0x04030201`", so the question is not without merit. But understanding the question goes a long way to answering it.

Answer (score 7):

> What's my mistake?

Using the wrong tool.

If you look up [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) in your favourite documentation, you'll see that it tells you how many bytes an object or type takes up. This has nothing to do with counting the number of significant bits in an integer *value*, and I don't know whence you got the notion that it would.

If you want to count significant bits in an integer, you will need either of:

1. A numerical algorithm to calculate this using bitwise arithmetic, or
2. A compiler intrinsic to do this for you, e.g. [`__builtin_clz` in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) (subtracted from total number of bits in the type — *now* you can use `sizeof`!)

Comment: If i went with option 1, what would be a really simple way to do it? could I take 0x04030201 and put it into its own int array, then count from the least significant digit until i hit "x0"? Does that approach make sense?

Answer (score 0):

> My code has to determine the size of this number in bits

What does *that* mean?

Is it:

1. the size of the smallest type native to your (unspecified) architecture which can represent your number?

   in this case, your code

   ```
   sizeof(num[2])*4
   ```

   is wrong because it (for some reason) assumes 4-bit chars. If you want to know the number of bits in a char, it's called `CHAR_BIT`. The `sizeof` expression correctly gives you the size in chars, so the code should be

   ```
   sizeof(num[2])*CHAR_BIT
   ```

   Note however that `sizeof(num[2])==sizeof(num[0])==sizeof(int)`, because every int is the same size: it doesn't depend on what value it holds.
2. Or did you want the smallest number of bits that can represent your number, ignoring what those bits are stored in?

   In this case *log<sub>2</sub>(n)* gives you the power of 2 your number represents. Taking the floor of that (truncating the floating-point value to an integer) gives you the number of the highest bit. Add one to get the number of bits (they start from zero, since you need one bit to represent 1=2<sup>0</sup>).

   If you want to do this without using logarithms, start by writing out your number in base 2 (start with a smaller number for testing, to save time). Hint: examine what happens when you divide it by 2.

Comment: I'm trying to do your option 2 and I want to keep it as simple as possible so preferably without logs. Can you clarify a bit further on how I could do that?

Comment: Have you chosen a number? I like 5, it's almost the smallest value that's not entirely trivial and will actually exercise all your required logic. Have you written it out in base 2? What did it look like? What is the correct answer (number of bits required to store 5)?

Comment: For 0x04030201, it takes a minimum of 27 bits. For 5 the binary is 101 so 3 bits minimum

Comment: Right, so what algorithm would get from the input "101" to the result 3? You have to actually try something. In fact, be prepared to try a few things.

Comment: would it be easier if i used a ceil(log2(x)) function instead? could i put the binary number in x?

Comment: You have all the information you need, assuming you've either done some _very basic_ programming before or are willing to learn. Come back with a question when you've actually written some code, if it's not behaving how you expect.